# Zend Framework query does not work?

Tags: zend-framework

I have problem with "SELECT" statement in Zend select.

```
public function listAnswers($sort_field = 'answer_id', $field = null, $value = null, $strict_filter = false, $client_id = null) {
    //here is $value
    // $value  = "abcd : <?\\?>"; 
    $value = $this->getDefaultAdapter()->quote("%".$value."%");

    if( !empty($field) && !empty($value) && $strict_filter == false){
            $select = $this->select()->where(" client_id != -99 ")->where($field . " like $value ")->order($sort_field);
    }
}
```

And error comes and my query printed was

```
    SELECT `answer`.* FROM `answer` WHERE ( client_id != -99 ) AND (client_id = '1') AND (answer_text LIKE '%abcd : <?\\\\?>%' ) ORDER BY `add_date` DESC
```

Record not come as appropriate `$value` has.

Comment: Try adding `%` before and after your `'part 1'` in the query. Like this: `%{$value}%` .

Comment: I have corrected my question again.. I have tried but it not works..@FrederickMarcoux

Comment: Why are you putting `<? ?>` in a MySQL query exactly? It could help me to answer you... @DevalShah

Comment: Actually I have tried Junk values like `"kdaod:" kfdlk <?,zc;l304003=2021\\[}{}W{{W[[?><m<":{}+_(!*^@#^@%#^%%%` and then my query break between and select statement was  SELECT `answer`.* FROM `answer` WHERE ( client_id != -99 ) AND (client_id = '1') AND (answer_text like '%\"kdaod:\" kfdlk _italic_ .My query break between php brackets.

Comment: For that, the `quote()` function should be enough... If it doesn't work, well I can't explain it!

Comment: Try using a `preg_match` to remove the PHP tags from the string...

Comment: php `<? ?>` brackets break query. @FrederickMarcoux

Comment: It seems to! I never tried by myself to be honnest. always filter and pregmatch the value before adding it to the query...

Comment: But I have to accept such junk values and using `preg_match` if i remove values than `like` statement not working.

Comment: @FrederickMarcoux just tried once for this situation and print ur query.It breaks.

Comment: Damn, you got a weird thing to do! Usually, we want to remove as much junk as possible from a SQL query to prevent SQL injections...

Comment: If i remove junk values `like` query not working and basically I have to accept `<? ?>`.

Comment: Well, I would like to help you but I can't! I've been working with MySQL for almost 7 years and I've never done something like this... Sorry if I'm useless... The best is to preg_match then tweak the query to accept the PHP tags!

Comment: If you're echoing the query to the HTML page, the `<` and `>` tags would need to be escaped or the browser will think they are HTML tags and not show them. Are you sure the query itself isn't working?

Comment: @TimFountain I have done `echo $select;exit;` so thats not problem for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is usually no need to quote values when using the select(), select() will normally provide the quotes by default. 
When using select() it is a good idea to use placeholders instead of concatenation because concatenation may not always work.

`$select->order()` requires a string to specify the query ('answer_id ASC'), unless you always want whatever the default is.

You set `$field` and `$value` to `null` by default, so testing for `!empty()` really doesn't make semantic sense.

Don't forget you have to actually fetch a result and return it.

```
//assuming a dbTable model where $this->select() is valid.
public function listAnswers($sort_field = 'answer_id', $field = null, $value = null, $strict_filter = false, $client_id = null) {
    //here is $value
    // $value  = "abcd : <?\\?>"; 
    //unless your values are really strange select() will provide the quotes
    //$value = $this->getDefaultAdapter()->quote("%".$value."%");
    //it may help to initialize select() before the loop
    $select = $this->select();
    if( !is_null($field) && !is_null($value) && $strict_filter == false){
        $select->where(" client_id != -99 ")
            //use placeholders when using the select()
            ->where("$field like ?" $value)
            //specify order by with a string ie: answer_id ASC
            ->order($sort_field . 'ASC');
    }
    //return the result
    return $this->fetchAll($select)
}
```

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussion in the comments think it's just displaying the SQL query in the browser which is not showing the 'part 1' bit of your string, as the browser will interpret the `<` and `>` characters as HTML tags and hide their contents. The code you are using for the query itself looks fine, so just use:

```
echo htmlspecialchars($select);exit;
```

for debugging to verify that the right query is being run.

Comment: U r right.My query is shown now.But result is not display.like `$value = "kdaod: kfdlk <?,zc;l304003=2021\\[}{}W{{W[[?><m<:{}+_(!*^@#^@%#^%%%";` and `like` query not display that record.`SELECT `answer`.* FROM `answer` WHERE ( client_id != -99 ) AND (client_id = '1') AND (answer_text like '%kdaod: kfdlk <?,zc;l304003=2021\\\\[}{}W{{W[[?><m<:{}+_(!*^@#^@%#^%%%%' ) ORDER BY `add_date` DESC` query is this

Comment: And if you run that query in MySQL directly does it return results?

Comment: no it don't works because ` $this->getDefaultAdapter()->quote("%".$value."%")` function added `\` to quotes.So like query don't match it.

Comment: I don't see extra quotes in the query posted in your comment, could you edit your question to include the full, not-working SQL query?